# How to open in vim output of some app

Tags: vim, editor, vi

Sometimes, I'd like to see output source code and standard output of compiled version of this code in vim simultaneously. Let's say, I have code `source.cpp` and compiled app `main`. Of course I can redirect `main` output to file and open it in `vim`:

```
 $ main > /tmp/main_output.txt
 $ vim /tmp/main_output.txt
```

However, it is too boring (especially if you have a lot of pairs code/app). So I'd like to write in `vim` something like

```
 :e source.cpp
 :vsp <someway obtained output of main>
```

How I can obtain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new scratch buffer (`:new`) and use `:read !{cmd}` to execute an external command and use its output:

```
:e source.cpp
:vnew | 0r !main
```